# texlive compilation error

Tags: xmltex

I creating the `fmt` file for ubuntu system 19.04 version. The FMT file is successfully created.

I am using the following compilation command `pdftex \&filename.fmt filename.xml`. The file is successfully compiled.

But i will try to configure the ubuntu 16.04 version server configuration. I am using the same `fmt` file for this server.

But the below mention error is throw while i am compiling the xml document.

`---!filename.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool`

`Fatal file format error ; i'm stymied)`

How to resolve this error. Could you please advice on this.

Comment: Did you try to copy the `.fmt` file from one machine to another?

Comment: @JosephWright yes i am using one machine to another

Answer (score 4):

Format files are memory dumps. As such, they have to be used only on systems of the same architecture, and using the same version of the TeX program involved. As such, it is almost never sensible to copy a `.fmt` file from one system to another: you would be much better to generate a format file on the second system.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not an uncommon issue that may be due to many reasons solutions were

Check root privileges for user/invoker including related folders and files

Attempt refreshing format (see user attempts in ALL the following tales of woe)

http://tatsunode.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/08/08/173200

Running as sudo ? https://www.prestonlee.com/tag/macports/

Check/Change environment variable(S)
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23485

Reinstall ! 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240255